# Convert TreeModel.toString back to TreeModel

Tags: java, jtree, treemodel

I am writing a java PlugIn for a robot, which involves using a dynamic `JTree`. When the program that uses the PlugIn is closed, and then reopened, any variables and object need to be stored in the robots `DataModel`. However, I cannot store a `JTree` in the programs data model, but I need to be able to store the tree so it can be changed and updated when the program is re-opened. So my question is, since i can store strings in the robots `DataModel`, is there a mechanic for converting the `.toString` of a `JTree` and its `TreeModel`, so that I can save the tree as a string, then convert it back when I reopen a program?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to parse string back. Or you can store a `JSON String` and convert it easily with any `JSON` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DefaultTreeModel already implements Serializable.  You don't need to use a String, just serialize the object to disk.  Something like:

```
FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("treeModel.obj"); 
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(file); 

out.writeObject(treeModel); 
out.close(); 
file.close();
```